# How do I query USNO catalogs using PyVO?

Tags: python, astronomy, astropy

I'm trying to use PyVO to query a given position (Ra,Dec in degrees) with USNO catalog using a simple cone search. The input parameters `pyvo.dal.scs.search` query takes are: query url, postion tuple, radius of search and verbosity.

The problem arises with the query url. Based on the USNO [website](http://www.nofs.navy.mil/data/fchpix/vo_nofs.html), the query url should be of the form of:

```
http://www.nofs.navy.mil/cgi-bin/vo_cone.cgi?CAT=USNO-B1&RA=1.0&DEC=-10.0&SR=0.1&VERB=1
```

However if I input

```
http://www.nofs.navy.mil/cgi-bin/vo_cone.cgi?CAT=USNO-B1&
```

as the query url, I get the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DALFormatError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-450dcb39a4d8> in <module>()
----> 1 uobjs_0 = vo.dal.scs.search('http://www.nofs.navy.mil/cgi-bin/vo_cone.cgi?CAT=USNO-B1&', (ra[0],dec[0]), 0.25)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvo-0.4.1-py2.7.egg/pyvo/dal/scs.pyc in search(url, pos, radius, verbosity)
     73     """
     74     service = SCSService(url)
---> 75     return service.search(pos, radius, verbosity)
     76 
     77 class SCSService(query.DALService):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvo-0.4.1-py2.7.egg/pyvo/dal/scs.pyc in search(self, pos, radius, verbosity)
    134         """
    135         q = self.create_query(pos, radius, verbosity)
--> 136         return q.execute()
    137 
    138     def create_query(self, pos=None, radius=None, verbosity=None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvo-0.4.1-py2.7.egg/pyvo/dal/scs.pyc in execute(self)
    341         pyvo.dal.query.DALQueryError
    342         """
--> 343         return SCSResults(self.execute_votable(), self.getqueryurl(True))
    344 
    345     def execute_votable(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvo-0.4.1-py2.7.egg/pyvo/dal/scs.pyc in execute_votable(self)
    369                                        "deprecated DEFINITIONS element")
    370         except Exception as e:
--> 371             raise query.DALFormatError(e, self.getqueryurl())
    372 
    373     def getqueryurl(self, lax=False):

DALFormatError: BadStatusLine: BadStatusLine
```

I also tried

```
http://www.nofs.navy.mil/cgi-bin/vo_cone.cgi?
```

which is similar to the working SDSS query url; however I get an error obviously as catalog name isn't included in the list of the input parameters mentioned above. Is there a way I can successfully query USNO catalogs using PyVO?

Comment: Kindly take 'colon' as ':' since being a newbie user doesn't allow me posting more than 2 links.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but have you tried using [astroquery.vizier}(http://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vizier/vizier.html) to query the USNO catalogs through Vizier?

Comment: @mommermi I've shifted to something different in the meanwhile. I posted a question on the astropy forum and got the suggestion for 'astroquery.Xmatch'. This seems to work well for my requirements. It works by cross-matching my catalog with the Vizier database(similar to your suggestion). Thanks a lot for your input!